# Overriding default column definittion for JPA/Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA and Hibernate.  In my database, the timestamp type isn't used.  So in my mapping classes, when it is Date for the Java type, I want it to be a Date for the type in my database.

I know I can do it on a case by case basis by doing this:

```
@Column(name="startdate", columnDefinition="date")
public Date startdate;
```

However, is there a way to set up a default columnDefinition, so I don't have to write it in every case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question not clear .But i think you are asking how to map java.util.Date(datetime ) as date to database .İf this is the case you can use  to store     only  date part of  startdate

```
@Temporal( TemporalType.DATE ) 
@Column(name="startdate", columnDefinition="date")
public Date startdate;
```